# Cannot start BIND9

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, unix, bind

I followed everything EXACTLY in [this tutorial](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/dns-server-setup-using-bind-in-ubuntu.html) for setting up DNS.
I set up everything on a blank server.

However, starting BIND9 failed:

```
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

I have Googled this, and it seems like there is not a good, solid answer.

Comment: Alex: Please follow the suggestions Florin, Yves, and Unknown gave, and come back here with the results. (Assuming you don't figure it out in the meantime.)

Comment: Can you post your named.conf in here? and try to find a clue from syslog after start / restarting named service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the logs, especially /var/log/daemon.log

There's got to be a clue in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Review your named.conf file and your procedures. Check the named daemon logs. Most likely you didn't create an rndc key, or it has the wrong permissions.

Usually this command would help:

> rndc-confgen -r /dev/urandom -a

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have SELinux or AppArmor, sometimes they mess with way file permissions are handled. /var/log/* should reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had "forwarders" in my named.conf.options file...and this was unrecognized.

Comment: I found the answer, and I did go through Florin's method.

Answer (score 0):

Find rndc.key and ensure that it has rw file permissions for root and read for user bind. The location below is on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, yours may vary.

```
-rw-r----- 1 root bind 77 Sep 17 17:31 /etc/bind/rndc.key
```