# why bind9 gives connection refused for permission denied error when it is 777

Tags: linux, bind, dns-zone

These questions didn't help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/172030/how-to-allow-bind-in-app-armor
[Cannot start BIND9](https://serverfault.com/questions/83081/cannot-start-bind9?rq=1)

I wanted to start `bind9` and saw that it gives permission denied in `syslog` as below:

```
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/bind9/query.log' failed: permission denied
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: configuring logging: permission denied
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: loading configuration: permission denied
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname named[27278]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname kernel: [1984823.682079] type=1400 audit(1454924244.439:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/bind9/query.log" pid=27279 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=0
```

Why it gives `permission error` when it is 777?

I thought maybe it is due to `zones` directory so I checked it too:

```
4 drwxr-sr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  7 18:45 zones
```

I checked zone files by `/usr/sbin/named-checkconf` but no error printed out on terminal.

content of `bind9`:

```
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 2389 Jan 18 14:04 bind.keys
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  237 Jan 18 14:04 db.0
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  271 Jan 18 14:04 db.127
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  237 Jan 18 14:04 db.255
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  353 Jan 18 14:04 db.empty
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  270 Jan 18 14:04 db.local
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 3048 Jan 18 14:04 db.root
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root bind  464 Feb  7 17:56 named.conf
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root bind  490 Jan 18 14:04 named.conf.default-zones
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root bind  333 Feb  7 18:47 named.conf.local
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root bind  455 Feb  7 18:33 named.conf.options
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root bind  890 Feb  7 13:22 named.conf.options.bak
4 -rw-r-----  1 bind bind   77 Feb  7 13:22 rndc.key
4 drwxr-sr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb  7 18:45 zones
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 1317 Jan 18 14:04 zones.rfc1918
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

`ls -las /var/lib/bind/` output:

```
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   53 Feb  7 13:22 bind9-default.md5sum
```

---

**EDIT 3:**
I have `apparmor`, does that mess with file permissons?

This question almost solved my problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/469866/bind-fatal-error-cant-open-custom-log

Some directories were not present so I created them. And path in `named.conf.options` was wrong, I corrected them to in order to point to a file which exists.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the error right there in your output:

```
Feb  8 09:37:24 aname kernel: [1984823.682079] type=1400 audit(1454924244.439:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/bind9/query.log" pid=27279 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=0
```

Add a

```
/var/log/bind9/query.log rw,
```

Stanza to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named`, restart apparmor and bind services, and you're good to go.

And do restore file system permissions to the log file.

Comment: I just didn't change permission for log file. All the bind folder needed to change plus `/var/cache/bind` folder

Comment: I know this question and answers are a bit old but I needed them so I thought I'd add my contribution to the preferred answer. You don't actually need to add anything to the apparmor file. It already includes an entry permitting bind log files to be in /var/log/named rather than /var/log/bind(9). Obviously this new directory has to have bind.bind ownership; if that's what named is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the ownership of the file:

```
chown bind:bind /var/log/bind9/query.log
```

Comment: Failed again! bind9 does not start. isc_stdio_open '/var/log/bind9/query.log' failed: permission denied

Comment: show output of `ls -lh /var/log/bind9/query.log`

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 bind bind 0 Feb  7 18:04 /var/log/bind9/query.log

Comment: Please see EDIT2 part, it may help too.

Answer (score 0):

I simply disabled and removed apparmor https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909965-How-to-disable-AppArmor-

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: But the link doesn't have the answer. The actual answer is disabling Apparmor. I simply provided a link showing show to disable Apparmor which is a different subject all together.